# Link two tables so a replacement in one is applied to the other

Tags: excel, vba

I have two tables in Excel that come from VBA data extraction from some other software.
[image: tables]

I’d like for the common values in the NAME column on each table to be linked.
If, for instance, I replaced ABC02 in the second table with ABC03 then the first table’s ABC02 would be replaced with ABC03 as well.
[image: replacement of values]

Conversely a change in the first table would lead to a change in the second one.

I tried using the Handle value to mark identical values with the following code:

```vb
Sub Test1()
Dim i, y As Integer
For i = 10 To 11
    y = 7
    Do Until y = 5
        y = y - 1
        If Range("C" & y).Value = Range("C" & i).Value Then
            Range("D" & y).Value = Range("B" & i).Value
        End If
    Loop
'' Action :
Next i
End Sub
```

Which gave this result:
[image: first result]

How do I efficiently do it both ways (meaning getting the handles of similar values for the other table as well) to get that result:
[image: intermediate desired result]

and how to go from there (or even if I should do that at all).

Answer (score 0):

This is a synchronisation issue and there is no quick and easy solution for that. What I would do is to use 2 event handlers of VBA: `Worksheet_SelectionChange` and `Worksheet_Change`. With the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` you can detect where the user has clicked and save the original value and address of the cell to some globally accessible variables. Then with the `Worksheet_Change` you can detect the user changes the value of the cell. Then you will have the original and the new value of cell. You need to manage multiple selection either, I give you a simple example in the following snippet.

```
Public origval As Variant, origaddr As Variant

Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    origval = Target.Cells(1).Value
    origaddr = Target.Cells(1).Address  ' this is to handle multiple selection
    Range(origaddr).Select              ' reset multiple selection
End Sub

Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' at this point 
    '     - origval contains the original value
    '     - origaddr and Target.Address contains the cell address (should be the same)
    '     - Target.Value contains the new value of the cell
    '     - Target.Address contains the cell address
    '     - Target.Parent.Name contains the name of worksheet
    '     - Target.Parent.Parent.Name contains the name of workbook
    '  so you know everything you need and you can decide how to go on
End Sub
```

NB: the trick in SelectionChange is rather a "dirty" one. This is just a reminder to handle multiple selection, too.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I knew I had to use Worksheet_Change and in the end someone gave me the full answer.

Answer (score 0):

Someone from another forum posted the following answer (so I'm posting it here in case anyone is looking for the same thing):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim x As Variant
Application.EnableEvents = False
Set f2 = Sheets("Image")
If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(3)) Is Nothing Then
    If Range(Target.Address).Value <> f2.Range(Target.Address).Value Then
        TargetImage = f2.Range(Target.Address).Value
        With f2
            Set x = Columns(3).Find(TargetImage)
            If Not x Is Nothing Then
                Pos = x.Address
                Do
                    If x.Row <> Target.Row Then
                        Cells(x.Row, "C") = Target.Value
                        'Modification of the Image sheet
                        f2.Cells(x.Row, "C") = Target.Value
                        f2.Range(Target.Address).Value = Target.Value
                    Else
                        Set x = .FindNext(x)
                    End If
                Loop While Not x Is Nothing And x.Address <> Pos
            End If
        End With
    End If
End If
Set f2 = Nothing
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This code assumes that:

1. There are 2 identical sheets and the second one is called "Image"
2. The user input is in the first sheet
3. The values we want to replace are both in the 3rd column
4. There are no duplicate values within the same table

If you want to execute another macro beforehand (like I do with my data extraction) you have to use that bit of code within that macro

```
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.EnableEvents = False

'Your code here...

ErrHandler:
   Application.EnableEvents = True
```

If somehow you modify that Worksheet_Change macro and get an error, you have to fix that error and enable events again with another macro like this one:

```
Sub ReenableEventsAfterError()
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```